# Is ngrx effect with filter valid?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

Example:

```
myAwesomeEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(MyAwesomeAction),
        concatMap(action => of(action).pipe(
            withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(myAwesomeSelector)))
        )),
        filter(([, myAwesomeValue]) => myAwesomeValue),
        map(() => myNotThatAwesomeAction())
    )
);
```

Few things to point out. As you can see the `effect` returns `action` only if the `filter` logic evaluates to `true`. That means the `effect` **sometimes returns** an `action`, **sometimes it doesn't**.

Is it a valid `effect`? Should I refrain from using `filter` operator in `effect` and replace it with `if` and a `Noop` action instead?

```
myAwesomeEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(MyAwesomeAction),
        concatMap(action =>
            of(action).pipe(
                withLatestFrom(
                    this.store$.pipe(select(myAwesomeSelector))
                )
            )
        ),
        map(([, myAwesomeValue]) => {
            if (myAwesomeValue) {
                return myNotThatAwesomeAction();
            }
            return NoopAction();
        })
    )
);
```

The second example is easy to test:

```
it('should return myNotThatAwesomeAction when myAwesomeValue is true', done => {
    store.overrideSelector(myAwesomeSelector, true);
    myAwesomeEffect$().subscribe(res => {
        expect(res).toEqual(myNotThatAwesomeAction());
        done();
    });
});

it('should return NoopAction when myNotThatAwesomeAction is false', () => {
    store.overrideSelector(myAwesomeSelector, false);
    myAwesomeEffect$().subscribe(res => {
        expect(res).toEqual(NoopAction());
        done();
    });
});
```

But what about the first example.

```
it('should return myNotThatAwesomeAction when myAwesomeValue is true', done => {
    store.overrideSelector(myAwesomeSelector, true);
    myAwesomeEffect$().subscribe(res => {
        expect(res).toEqual(myNotThatAwesomeAction());
        done();
    });
});

it('should not return myNotThatAwesomeAction when myNotThatAwesomeAction is false', done => {
    store.overrideSelector(myAwesomeSelector, false);
    // This won't work since the effect won't return anything

    myAwesomeEffect$().subscribe(res => {
        expect(res).not.toEqual(myNotThatAwesomeAction());
        done();
    });
});
```

What should I replace the second test case with? (while not using third party libs)

Update:

To test an effect which contains `filter` operator I choose this way:

```
it('myAwesomeEffect$ does not return anything when myAwesomeValue is false', done => {
    myEffects.myAwesomeEffect$.subscribe(
        () => done.fail(),
        () => done.fail(),
        () => {
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
            done();
        }
    );

});
```

So if it throws, error or if it produces value we fail the test.

Comment: FYI: [NgRx Effects Best Practices](https://www.spreaker.com/user/ng-conf/e066-ngrx-effects-best-practices) mentions not to use `withLatestFrom` in effects, but rather to use the ngrx operator [`concatLatestFrom`](https://ngrx.io/api/effects/concatLatestFrom)

Comment: concatLatestFrom was introduced in v12, I'm currently using an older version

Answer (score 2):

Using the filter operator to "stop" the effect stream is valid.

Comment: Lets say I implement the flow with filter. How would you test the case where the filter returns false so the effect doesn't return action?

One way would be to test that the myNotThatAwesomeAction action doesn't get called. But it also means that if in the future I extend the logic and return a new action based on some condition, then the original test will also pass, since `myNotThatAwesomeAction` doesn't get called. An other action gets called instead.

Comment: Depends what you're using for tests, if you're using marble tests than you just don't expect that the stream emits a value

Comment: How the unit test would look like without marbles?

Comment: https://github.com/hirezio/observer-spy

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Please check the post again. I added the test related question and examles there.

Comment: Frankly spoken, it's probably better to join the ngrx or angular discord channel. It's better to have a chat about.